# How do I mention a list of users with a discord bot every 6 hours- python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to get a discord bot to ping some users every 6 hours to remind them to do something. (00:00 GMT, 6:00 etc)

for starters I tried to get the ping by creating a simple command.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
        return

  if message.content.startswith('$inspire'):
    names = ["Skapis9999","MEE6","Dank Memer"]
    discriminators = [XXXX,4876,5192]
    for x in range(len(names)):
      user = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name = names[x], discriminator = discriminators[x])
    # user = client.get_user_info(id) is used to get User from ID
      if user is None:  # or just: if x and x.user
        await message.channel.send('Null user')
      await message.channel.send(message.channel, user.mention)
    return
```

The error here says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mention'` and I get the Null user message. Why is the user object empty?

Then I tried to make it a loop

```
import asyncio
import datetime as dt

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

#initiate
@tasks.loop(hours=6)
async def ping(ctx):
    message_channel = bot.get_channel(821920520169062419)   #821920520169062419 is channel id
    await message_channel.send("test 1")
    

async def before_msg1():
    for _ in range(60*60*6):  # loop the hole 6 hours
        if dt.datetime.now().hour == 10+12:  # 24 hour format
            print('It is time for the Event')
            names = ["Skapis9999","MEE6","Dank Memer"]
            discriminators = [111,4876,5192]
            for x in range(len(names)):  
                user = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name = names[x], discriminator = discriminators[x])
                #user = discord.utils.get(message.server.members, name =names[x], discriminator = discriminators[x])  
                await message_channel.send(message_channel, user.mention)
            return
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)# wait 0.01 seconds before looping again.
```

The main problem here is that I must initiate the bot when it's that time of the day I want it to ping the users. In addition I get an error for the syntax in the await line.

Comment: Have you tried using ids instead of name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input arguments to send a message are wrong. send() has no input argument which is a channel, because it's a method of a channel.

**WRONG**
`await message_channel.send(message_channel, user.mention)`

**CORRECT**
`await message_channel.send(user.mention)`

Now it should work to send the message, but your code has a few other things to fix:

1. Your ping command is not a command, it's a task. Due to this fact, it has no context as input argument. This doesn't matter, because you don't use your variable `ctx`, but if you would try, you will receive an error.
2. Instead of doing:

```py
for x in range(len(names)):  
     user = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name = names[x], discriminator = discriminators[x])
```

, you can do:

```py
for name,discriminator in zip(names,discriminators):
   user = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name = name, discriminator = discriminator)
```

(more about this zip() you can find [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) for example)

So the new task code is:

```py
@tasks.loop(hours=6)
async def before_msg1():
     print('It is time for the Event')
     names = ["Skapis9999","MEE6","Dank Memer"]
     discriminators = [111,4876,5192]
     for name,discriminator in zip(names,discriminators):
          user = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members,
                                   name = name,
                                   discriminator = discriminator)
          await message_channel.send(user.mention)
```

This would to the mentions every 6 hours after the start of the bot. So you should be aware the time which this function is executed, depends on your machine timing and the bot start time. If you want to run this to a specific daytime, you can use libaries like apscheduler (more about this you find [here](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) or do something like this:

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=30.0)
async def task_everyday_at_5_59():
     # sleep until the specified datetime
     now = datetime.datetime.today()
     time_aim = datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 28, 5, 59)
     while now > time_aim:
          time_aim = time_aim + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
     await asyncio.sleep(abs(time_aim - now).total_seconds())
     # do something
```

HINT: DON'T FORGET TO START YOUR TASK!